# Chunks to Symbols in Gnuradio 3.8

Tags: gnuradio

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_C%2B%2B) to build a flow graph with GnuRadio 3.8. However, I am unsure what settings should I use for Chunks to Symbols and get some errors when I execute the flow graph:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/top_block.py", line 186, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/top_block.py", line 164, in main
    tb = top_block_cls()
  File "/home/user/top_block.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.digital_chunks_to_symbols_xx_0 = digital.chunks_to_symbols_ic(1+1j, 1-1j, -1+1j, -1-1j, 1)
TypeError: make() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 5 were given

>>> Done (return code 1)
```

My flow graph is:
[image]
My settings for Chunks to Symbols are as follows:

Input type: int

Output type: complex

Symbol table: 1+1j, 1-1j, -1+1j, -1-1j

Dimension: 1

Num ports: 1

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Symbol table: $1+1j, 1-1j, -1+1j, -1-1j$

The Symbol table needs to be a python list/array - `[1+1j, 1-1j, -1+1j, -1-1j]`